# Retrieve sql data and generate as json file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to retrieve the data from mySQL and generate as JSON file.
But the output is just showing only 1 row.
There are many rows inside the database table.
What is wrong with this code?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM form_element";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$response = array();
$data_array = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $id = $data['id'];
      $name = $data['name'];
      $email = $data['email'];
      $phone = $data['phone'];
      $address = $data['address'];
      $data_array = array(
         'name' => $name, 
         'email' => $email, 
         'phone' => $phone, 
         'address' =>  $address
      );
   }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}
$response['data_array'] = $data_array;
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting `$data_array` every time in the loop.

So, this part:

```
$data_array = array(
  'name' => $name, 
  'email' => $email, 
  'phone' => $phone, 
  'address' =>  $address
);
```

should be changed to:

```
$data_array[] = array(
  'name' => $name, 
  'email' => $email, 
  'phone' => $phone, 
  'address' =>  $address
);
```

Then each row is added to the `$data_array`.